# How do I define python methods for generated classes dynamically?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a way to generate many classes with different methods that depend on a parameter. What I currently have is:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def method(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class KlassMethod:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __call__(self, base, x):
        return x * self.a + base.y


klass = type("Klass5", (Base,), {'method': KlassMethod(5)})
obj = klass(8)
obj.method(5)
```

In short, I need the class `KlassMethod` for the method because I need to encapsulate the parameter `a` inside, because it can be different for different `klass`. On the other hand, I need to have the access to the object's attribute `y`. When I run the code above I get the error:

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

If I didn't have the parameter `a`, I would implement the method as a function like this, that works fine:

```
def method(base, x):
    return x + base.y
```

As the solution, I also tried to use `functools.partial` like this:

```
from functools import partial

...

def klass_method(self, x, a):
    return x * a + self.y

klass = type("Klass", (Base,), {'method': partial(klass_method, a=5)})
...
```

The error is the same.

It looks like `__call__` does not work as expected if we call it with the instance. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: "I need the class KlassMethod for the method because I need to encapsulate the parameter a inside, because it can be different for different klass" Have you tried just using `functools.partial` to find the parameter?

Comment: Anyway, please talk me through the steps of what you want to happen when `obj.method(5)` runs. It should look up the `method` attribute of `obj`, find the `KlassMethod` instance which is held by the dynamically-created `klass` type... and then what? Call it, yes? So that should invoke the `__call__`, and then... obviously `self` will be `obj`, but where do you expect the values for `base` and `x` to come from? Why/how?

Comment: Can't `Base.method` take a `KlassMethod` instance as an argument? I feel like we need a bit more context in regards to what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `self` will be the instance of `KlassMethod`, not `obj`. You can check it by running the script.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I did try `functools.partial`. It led to the same error.

Comment: Er, right. I got confused and I realized it while I was trying to write an answer. The short version is that the interface is designed with the expectation that you use plain functions here. The long version is that I am pretty sure you can make this work, but it will require understanding the descriptor protocol, and I don't think I am quite up to the task at the moment.

Comment: I didn't mean to use `functools.partial` to help implement this. I meant to use `functools.partial` to *replace it completely*. Except actually now I don't think I would even get that complicated. Why do you need multiple classes at all? Why not just *instances* that store the parameter and use it as needed? What problem are you trying to solve with this setup?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please, have a look at the description. I modified it adding `functools.partial`. I did replace `KlassMethod` with the partial function, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```py
def make_class(a):
    class Klass(Base):
        def method(self, x):
            return x * a + self.y
    return Klass

klass = make_class(5)
```

Here the `a` is [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) over, but you could also make it work as a class attribute:

```py
def make_class2(a):
    class Klass(Base):
        def method(self, x):
            return x * self.a + self.y
    Klass.a = a
    return Klass
```

I think it is generally simpler to write a local class declaration than to dynamically call the `type` constructor, but if you want to do it that way (e.g. because each dynamic class having different class names is important to you) then that's still possible:

```py
def make_class(a):
    def method(self, x):
        return x * a + self.y
    return type('Klass5', (Base,), {'method': method})

def make_class2(a):
    def method(self, x):
        return x * self.a + self.y
    return type('Klass5', (Base,), {'method': method, 'a': a})
```